# Make <br> optional for the last line

Tags: php, regex, line

So I want to turn the line after `/r` completely red, but only this line.

So far I've got this (this only works because `\n` gets replaced by `<br>` earlier; it doesn't matter at the moment):

```
$str = preg_replace("/\/r(.*)<br>/", '<font color="red">$1</font><br>', $str);
```

This works so far, but only if there is really a line break. If you just type one line, it won't make it red.

Is there any way to get the end of a line, or the end of the whole text?

Comment: Is that, oh yeah HTML parsing with reg ex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @ValentinMercier: Did you read the complete question? Or just assumed that the question is about parsing HTML as you saw a `<br>` in it? :)

Comment: Please include some example HTML with the input, otherwise there's no way for us to test the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to make `<br>` optional for last line. You can use:

```
$str = preg_replace('~/r(.*?)(?:<br>|$)~uis', '<font color="red">$1</font><br>', $str);
```

Comment: If you want to do this you should probably add `uis` as flags of your regexp (unicode entities, ignore case, single-line mode)